# change range axes 3D-plot in R

Tags: r

I have the following 3d-plot, and I would like to change the vertical axis' range: I'd like it to go from 0 to 1 instead of from 0 to 0.5. 
Can someone tell me how to do this?

3d-plot:

```
library("rgl")
coord.1=c(1,0,0) 
coord.4=c(0,1,0) 
coord.5=c(1,0,0.5) 

pyrcolor="red" 
triangles3d(rbind(coord.1,coord.4,coord.5),color= "red") 
axes3d()
```

Comment: Please read the help material at `?plot3d`.

Comment: I already did and I could not figure it out, hence the question

Comment: Did you see the `xlim`,  `ylim`, and `zlim` parameters? (My experience is that sometimes the ylim and zlim are switched from what I expect.)